# Internet Proxy server in c#

Tags: c#, webproxy

I need to implement a basic internet proxy in c#. Initial investigation it seems like it could be a tricky area.  Does anyone have pointers to starting points, resources or open source implementations?

Comment: Do you mean an Internet Proxy Server? Please be specific on what you mean when you say "web proxy".

Comment: I meant a prOxy server, updated title. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Fiddler core](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Core/).    You can use Reflector to look at the code.

Comment: I've used fiddler many times before but didn't know about fiddler core. Very nice stand alone (no fiddler ui) inet prxy server.  Thanks for the pointer.